# GraphQL bad request when using variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I am new to GraphQL and am in a situation where I need to make a mutation request using apollo. I am largely unfamiliar with syntax and I am unable to find a solution to my problem elsewhere.

When I use the following query, I get a status code 200 back:

```
const CREATE_USER = gql`mutation Mutation {
  createUser(firstName: "corn", uid: "unique", contactNumber: "123467891") {
    user {
      uid
      contactNumber
      email
      firstName
      lastName
      gender
    },
    ok
  }
}`
```

Hover, when I try to implement variables with the following query, I get a 400 bad request code back:

```
const CREATE_USER = gql`mutation createUser($firstName: String, $lastName: String, $uid: String $contactNumber: String) {
        user {
            contactNumber
            email
            firstName
            lastName
            gender
            dob
        }
        ok
}
```

I've looked at examples and adjusted by query with variables to fit, but I am still unable to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong. I know it's probably a simple syntax problem but I'm too unfamiliar with graphql to figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out the correct syntax. I had tried variations like this, but I guess I made mistakes which caused errors. This time I got it right.

```
const CREATE_USER = gql`mutation createUser($contactNumber: String, $uid: String!, $email: String, $firstName: String, $lastName: String) {
createUser(contactNumber: $contactNumber, uid: $uid, email: $email, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName) {
    user {
        contactNumber
        uid
        email
        firstName
        lastName
        gender
        dob
    }
    ok
   }
}`
```